# Cd into the no name directory

Tags: linux, directory

I am in my flash directory

```
# cd /media/Flash/
# ls -al
drwxrwxr-x 10 root root 4096 Feb 22 14:35 .
drwxrwxr-x  7 root root 4096 Feb 20 15:57 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 2024 Feb 17 09:17 file1
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  436 Feb 17 10:47 file2
drw-rw-r--  1 root root 2666 Feb 20 09:43
```

So:

How can I use cd command to go into the no name directory?

Comment: It's must have a name. `printf '%s\n' [!f]* | od -t x2` to see what is it

Comment: Or, for a more human-readable output, try `printf '%s\n' [!f]* | od -c` or `find . -type d -printf "'%f'\n"`.

Comment: Thank all, I am in tty. So I can't copy `' '` and cd `' '`; when I write `cd ' '` it tells no such file or directory. But in psudo terminal when I copy it I can cd to it... how can I do that in tty?

Comment: The answer will depend on the actual name. Please [edit] your question and post the output of `printf '%s\n' [!f]* | od -c`. You can almost certainly cd into it by typing `cd \ ` then hitting tab, but we need to see the output to give more precise instructions.

Comment: You could also try `ls -l | hexdump -C` to see what characters/bytes the dir name is made of.

Comment: One of `cd ?` or `cd ??` will likely work, assuming the directory name has less than three characters. `ls -lq` should tell you the numbers of characters.

Comment: A simple `cd [!f]*` is all that is needed to get into that directory, assuming that indeed all your other files begin with an `f`.

Comment: `cd */`, since you have no other directories at that level (that we can see)

Answer (score 1):

Shell wildcard should expand to all of them, even this one.  So you could do it by removing the rest of the contents and `cd *`, or by some more elaborate loop to check against the existing ones. I'm not sure what exactly that is, but `x=$(ls | tail -n1) && cd "$x"` could maybe work. It can't be an empty string, because that's not allowed by the filesystem.

Anyway, you should rename this thing as soon as possible into something normal. Try `ls | hexdump` to see what exactly is that thing (it could be any nonprintable character, or even something unicode that your terminal cannot display).